# discord-xp problem with my discord bot "Cannot read property 'cache' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I was trying to set up discord-xp for my bot, but whenever I tried using the leaderboard command, it showed an error:

```
username: client.users.cache.get(key.userID) ? client.users.cache.get(key.userID).username : "Unknown",
                       ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'cache' of undefined
    at c:\Users\224is\OneDrive\Documents\Bot work\node_modules\discord-xp\index.js:289:32
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Function.computeLeaderboard (c:\Users\224is\OneDrive\Documents\Bot work\node_modules\discord-xp\index.js:283:19)
    at Client.<anonymous> (c:\Users\224is\OneDrive\Documents\Bot work\index.js:61:32)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:94:5)
```

Here is the code, problem is in the method at the end:

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const levels = require("./models/levels.js");
var mongoUrl;

class DiscordXp {
  
  /**
  * @param {string} [userId] - Discord user id.
  * @param {string} [guildId] - Discord guild id.
  */
  
  static async fetch(userId, guildId, fetchPosition = false) {
    if (!userId) throw new TypeError("An user id was not provided.");
    if (!guildId) throw new TypeError("A guild id was not provided.");
    
    const user = await levels.findOne({
      userID: userId,
      guildID: guildId
    });
    if (!user) return false;
    
    if (fetchPosition === true) {
      const leaderboard = await levels.find({
        guildID: guildId
      }).sort([['xp', 'descending']]).exec();
      
      user.position = leaderboard.findIndex(i => i.userID === userId) + 1;
    }
    
    
    /* To be used with canvacord or displaying xp in a pretier fashion, with each level the cleanXp stats from 0 and goes until cleanNextLevelXp when user levels up and gets back to 0 then the cleanNextLevelXp is re-calculated */
    user.cleanXp = user.xp - this.xpFor(user.level);
    user.cleanNextLevelXp = this.xpFor(user.level + 1) - this.xpFor(user.level);
    
    return user;
  }
  
  /**
  * @param {string} [guildId] - Discord guild id.
  * @param {number} [limit] - Amount of maximum enteries to return.
  */
  
  
  static async fetchLeaderboard(guildId, limit) {
    if (!guildId) throw new TypeError("A guild id was not provided.");
    if (!limit) throw new TypeError("A limit was not provided.");
    
    var users = await levels.find({ guildID: guildId }).sort([['xp', 'descending']]).exec();
    
    return users.slice(0, limit);
  }
  
  /**
  * @param {string} [client] - Your Discord.CLient.
  * @param {array} [leaderboard] - The output from 'fetchLeaderboard' function.
  */
  
  static async computeLeaderboard(client, leaderboard, fetchUsers = false) {
    if (!client) throw new TypeError("A client was not provided.");
    if (!leaderboard) throw new TypeError("A leaderboard id was not provided.");
    
    if (leaderboard.length < 1) return [];
    
    const computedArray = [];
    
    if (fetchUsers) {
      for (const key of leaderboard) {
        const user = await client.users.fetch(key.userID) || { username: "Unknown", discriminator: "0000" };
        computedArray.push({
          guildID: key.guildID,
          userID: key.userID,
          xp: key.xp,
          level: key.level,
          position: (leaderboard.findIndex(i => i.guildID === key.guildID && i.userID === key.userID) + 1),
          username: user.username,
          discriminator: user.discriminator
        });
      }
    } else {
      leaderboard.map(key => computedArray.push({
        guildID: key.guildID,
        userID: key.userID,
        xp: key.xp,
        level: key.level,
        position: (leaderboard.findIndex(i => i.guildID === key.guildID && i.userID === key.userID) + 1),
        username: client.users.cache.get(key.userID) ? client.users.cache.get(key.userID).username : "Unknown",
        discriminator: client.users.cache.get(key.userID) ? client.users.cache.get(key.userID).discriminator : "0000"
      }));
    }
    
    return computedArray;
  }
}

module.exports = DiscordXp;
```

Comment: Can you provide more or the entire file? It may not be possible to answer this question with the code provided.

Comment: addded more code

Comment: What is your discord.js version? I still cannot see anything wrong with this. The full code may be required.

Comment: this is discord v12

Comment: i also added more code the full code

Comment: From the current code, everything does indeed look fine. Maybe, it is an issue with the code calling these methods instead?

Comment: Please show _your_ code and not discordxp... `c:\Users\224is\OneDrive\Documents\Bot work\index.js`

Answer (score 0):

This means that `client` is NOT an instance of `Client`. If you are using a command handler, make sure the arguments are passed in with the correct order. This is a common mistake with command handlers. I cannot provide any code as I could not find the place where the error occurred.